# Installing statsmodels - Python 3.6 32 bit

Tags: python, windows, statsmodels

Morning,

I have Python 3.6 32 bit install on a Windows machine.
I have `numpy` and `scipy` installed. I have also installed `Visual Studio 2015`.

When I execute the  `pip install - U statsmodels` into the command line, I got the following errors:

```
1) No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
2) error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\ProgramFiles (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
```

Now:
1) I'm not sure why this is happening, as I do have numpy installed

2) I've navigated to this directory, but I can only get as far as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC

Any thoughts on the above?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: do you have numpy+mlk installed? https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: I have numpy, haven't heard of mlk

Comment: Try to remove numpy, and install the numpy+mlk you can find in the link I gave :)

Comment: Thanks! It was actually an issue with Visual Studio, I needed to do a custom install and install the SDK. Thanks!